# Помогите разобраться в коде python3, работа функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Задача "Большие буквы"

Напишите функцию capitalize(), которая принимает слово из маленьких
латинских букв и возвращает его же, меняя первую букву на большую.

```
def capitalize(word):
    first_letter_small = word[0]
    first_letter_big = chr(ord(first_letter_small) - ord('a') + ord('B'))
    return first_letter_big + word[1:]
 
source = input().split()
res = []
for word in source:
    res.append(capitalize(word))
print(' '.join(res))
```

как понимаю я (построчно от инпута):

1. сначала вводим 2 слова разделенных пробелом, например jabra kadabra
2. создается пустой список res
3. запускается цикл for для набивания списка
4. res.append(capitalize(word)) запускает функцию

в функции:

5. извлечение первой буквы первого слова
6. ??? первую букву убрали заменили на большую, но мне непонятно chr(ord(first_letter_small) - ord('a') + ord('A')):

   ord(first_letter_small) - это это буква j минус ord('a') + ord('A')) (почему а и А, или пайтон понимает,
   что нужно взять не "а" и "А" (или 'z' 'Z'), а ord(first_letter_small), т.е. 'j'
   если подставить 'a' 'B', происходит смещение: будут подставлены символы на 1 больше в алфавите
7. возврат первой заглавной склеенной с остальным словом

??? поскольку слова 2, функция автоматически вызывается 2 раза?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала разберемся что такое функция `ord()`.
Она возвращает числовое представление для указанного символа.
Т.е. если мы возьмем к примеру символ `b` - то в числовом представлении это будет - `98` отнимем от этого числа числовое значение символа `a`, по таблице понятно, что это - `97`, получим следующее:

```
98 - 97 = 1
```

Прибавим числовое представление символа `A`, т.е:

```
1 + 65 = 66

66 = B
```

[image: Кодировка символов]